# Qt exposes a QWidget's handle with getDC - how do I get a QWidget's handle on the Mac?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I can make native win32 calls (GetPixel/SetPixel) on a QWidget by using QWidget::getDC .. How do I do this for Mac builds?

Using QImage/QPixmap for retrieving pixel information is not an option because I need very fast access to what's already been drawn onto a QWidget via QPainter on both Windows and Mac.

The reason I am using GetPixel on windows is to implement 2d mouse picking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but if you want the underlying window system handle/ID, you can use [`QWidget::winId()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#winId) which returns `HIViewRef` or `NSView` on Mac depending on if it's Carbon or Cocoa version of Qt library.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks so much.